# Creating an account with a username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have followed the [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address/%22devise%20wiki%22) to enable username login with devise (instead of email).  But I can't figure out how to enable username signup/registration with devise.

I have changed my registration view to prompt for a first and last name and a password.

app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:

```
<h3>Sign up</h3>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <div><%= f.label :firstname, "First Name", :autofocus => true %><br />
  <script type="text/javascript">window.onload = function() {document.getElementById('user_firstname').focus();}</script>
  <%= f.text_field :firstname %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :lastname, "Last Name", :autofocus => true %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :lastname %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

I've edited my model to generate a username from the first and last name:

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:username]

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  #attr_accessor :username
  validates_presence_of :firstname, :lastname, :unique => true 
  after_validation :createUsername
  attr_accessible :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :firstname, :lastname
  #attr_protected :password

  def createUsername
    # create username from first-last name
    firstnamePart=self.firstname[0,1].downcase
    lastnamePart=self.lastname[0,5].downcase
    username=lastnamePart + firstnamePart
    count=0
    while username.length != 7
      username=username + count.to_s
      count +=1
    end
    self.username=username
    #verify username uniqueness?
  end


  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
      conditions = warden_conditions.dup
      if login = conditions.delete(:login)
        where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
      else
        where(conditions).first
      end
    end
end
```

But when I try to sign up I get the following error.  Text will have to do because I don't have enough 'reputation' to post images:

```
Sign up
1 error prohibited this user from being saved:
Email can't be blank
```

so, devise is still looking for an email during the signup/registration phase.  I assume I have to edit devise's controller but that didn't get installed in the following commands

1. rails g devise:install
2. rails g devise user
3. rails g devise:views

So my rails app is probably using a default devise controller (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/devise-1.5.4/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) but I didn't see any references to 'email' in there.

How do I change devise to accept a username during signup/registration?  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: The first thing I would check would be to make sure the `email` column is gone from the `users` table.

Comment: ok, the email field was still in the users table but I have removed it.

Comment: so, after removing the email column from the users table I get this error after restarting my app and attempting to register a new user with a first and last name:  http://pastebin.com/PWfBNxu0

Comment: fyi:  here's how I removed the email column:  http://pastebin.com/4dBAhRP3

Comment: That looks right. Make sure you've also done a `rake db:test:prepare`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you discard email at all in your login system. That's quite different from the Devise article which still have email attribute but use uername to login only.

Before fixing the issue, double think it. This is REALLY NOT A GOOD PRACTICE.

1. Most of the common Devise modules relying on email won't work, confirmable, password recovery, password confirmation etc. Do you really want that? What if an user lost password and recover? No way in this system!
2. There is no way you can inform users any important notice in your app, say a major TOS change.
3. You are inviting spam in your system.

Comment: 1.  "Do you really want that?"  No, figured I'd resolve that after I could create a user.
2.  Same as above, I'd figure out how to resolve that after I get a user created.
3.  Yes I would be but after a while I would have no more new users and would disable the registration process.  or think of something else.

Comment: @olveram, if you don't want that, just don't do it. Making this feature pass will need lots of hackings on Devise for no email cases. If the hackings are only good for this unwanted feature, it's a waste of time.

Comment: my problem is that some users won't have email addresses and I wanted it to be easy for them to sign up.

Comment: looks like my phone does not have the capability to mark this answer as accepted for my question so I'll do it when I get home thank you

Comment: @olveram, my pleasure. If they don't have email, even Facebook and Twitter can't let them in. Google can, but there are lots of sophisticated mechanisms. For easier login you can apply third party login in the future, where email is not a must with an authentication token.

Answer (score 0):

Did you "Modify config/initializers/devise.rb to have:"

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that in the original post:
  config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]

Comment: heading out for an appointment, be back later this evening.  Thanks for all the help, i appreciate it.